# Instatiate prefab and set its script parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this script which has to spawn zombies.
The zombie prefab has a script with the public variable `Health`.
How do I set this health per zombie, for example, give each zombie 10 more health than the previous?
This is the spawn function (C#):

```
void SpawnZombie()
    {
        ZombieClone = Instantiate(ZombiePrefab, RandomSpawnPoint(), Quaternion.identity);//Spawns a copy of ZombiePrefab at SpawnPoint
    }
```

It works perfectly but now it needs to spawn zombies with a 'custom' Health value. How would I do this?

Comment: Why don't you set it after? `ZombieClone.GetComponent<MeZombieScript>().SetHealth(<random_health_here>);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
// Spawns a copy of ZombiePrefab at SpawnPoint
var ZombieClone = Instantiate(ZombiePrefab, RandomSpawnPoint(), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
// Retrieve the script from the GameObject
ZombieScript zs = ZombieClone.GetComponent<ZombieScript>();
// Set the desired value of the script
zs.Health = 20;
```

Comment: Will this automatically take the last spawned zombie? Because I am spawning one every 5 seconds.

Comment: This will take the zombie created by the `Instantiate` command.